# MySQL: I want to pass an array to a function and see it iterate through each element of the array

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have the following code so far:

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION Iteration(InputArray CHAR) 
RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
    RETURN 
    SELECT Max(IF(Stock = InputArray, ValueFrom, NULL)) AS Stock FROM DatabaseName.TableName LIMIT 1;
END 

delimiter ;

SET @Stocks = (SELECT ColumnName FROM DatabaseName.TableName LIMIT 1);
SELECT Iteration(@Stocks)FROM DatabaseName.TableName;
```

What I'm interested in doing is passing an array to the `Iteration` function, which would then be operated on by looking up the corresponding value in the `DatabaseName` database, spitting back out a corresponding decimal for each value in the input array-- in other words, one array in, another array out.

I think I instantiated everything correctly, but I keep getting the following error:

> Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION applications.Iteration does not exist

For example, I have the variables `AAA, BBB, CCC`, etc, which are stock inventory codes. I want to pass an array of these variables to the procedure/function, and then go onto get back an array as well. In this case, it would be `1.7, 1.3, and 1.8`.

There's a few questions I have:

1. Does this make sense-- that is, can I pass an array to a function like this?
2. If 1. is yes, am I passing the array to the function properly?
3. Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to nail down the logic you actually want for the SQL query.  You want to take the `MAX` value of the `ValueFrom` column, but only for those records where the `Stock` is contained in the input array.  This can be accomplished by doing a simple `SELECT`, along with a `WHERE` clause which filters out the non matching records, e.g.

```
SELECT ValueFrom
FROM DatabaseName.TableName
WHERE Stock IN ('stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3')
```

Of course, we will need to replace the list of stocks with the input array.  I would use a stored procedure here:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Iteration(IN inputArray VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ValueFrom FROM DatabaseName.TableName WHERE Stock IN (', inputArray, ')');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Usage:**

```
SET @inputArray = '\'stock1\',\'stock2\',\'stock3\'';
CALL Iteration(@inputArray);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code-- correct me if I'm wrong, but Procedures aren't capable of returning values. Instead, what you did was to use a procedure to set a SELECT statement that then gets executed?

Comment: Additionally, I'm still getting the "Error Code: 1305. PROCEDURE DataBaseName.Iteration does not exist"

Comment: Why do you need a value returned?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand it now. Any idea on why I'm still getting an error code?

Comment: What are the real names of your database and tables?  I believe this is the source of the problem.

Comment: I fixed that, however, now, I'm getting "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'stock1' in 'where clause'".

Comment: Your edit on the quotation marks at least got it to return something, however, it seems like the Procedure is only returning the last value in the array of inputArray.

Comment: Wait...do you intend to return _multiple_ values from your function?  Or do you really just want the `MAX` from a query?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I intend to return multiple values from the procedure/function--One input value to one output value. The MAX function is only there to prevent it if the same value somehow appears twice.

Comment: Please update your original question with the exact query you want to perform.  Use example data in place of variables.

Comment: I subbed in the first three variables, per your recommendation.

Comment: What value do you want to use if an inventory code does _not_ appear in the table?  I will update my query accordingly.

Comment: I'm hoping that will never happen, simply because the person executing the function should have all product codes in front of them.

Comment: I updated my answer, which involved only removing the `MAX` function.  Now, you will get a list of matching stocks.